# Intervalo de minutos restantes entre campo e dataAtual

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, phpmyadmin

estou tentando criar uma query direto no mysql em que deve me retornar algum valor caso o intervalo de tempo da datahoraatual e do meu campo datareg seja de 02 minutos.

```
SELECT * FROM tabelax WHERE grade = 19 AND NOW() <= DATE_SUB(datareg, INTERVAL 02 MINUTE)
```

Tentei usar o now() com date_sub meu campo datareg, mas acho que estou boiando.

Tentei também com DATEDIFF , mas não está retornando

```
SELECT * FROM tabelax WHERE grade = 19 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), datareg) < 2
```

Alguma sugestão ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta com essa query

```
SELECT *
FROM tabelax
WHERE datareg > NOW() - INTERVAL 02 MINUTE
```

espero resposta :)

edit:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabelax
WHERE 
datareg >= NOW() - INTERVAL 02 MINUTE AND 
datareg <= NOW()
```

Comment: poxa irmão obrigado pela atenção, uai rapaz quase deu certo aqui porém ta ao contrário, ele ta me retornando quando minutos são maiores a 02 minutos.

Explicar melhor, supondo que:
datareg:    2019-10-10 09:40:00
dataatual: 2019-10-10 09:42:00

Se o resultado de datareg-datatual > 0 e  <=2
então ele me retornaria resultado, caso contrario não.

Via php é de boa fazer isso, agora direto no mysql estou apanhando rsrs já li e reli algumas partes da documentação da parte de condicional, mas ainda não ficou claro.

Comment: E virando o simbolo? <

Comment: opa falei errado,  
datareg seria   2019-10-10 09:40:00  
datatual seria  **2019-10-10 09:38:00**  

ou seja, subtraindo falta 2 minutos né, tentei  isso porém quando a datatual for por exemplo 09:41 não é pra mostrar resultado, somente mostrar enquanto tiver entre 09:38 e 09:40  
  
`... AND (final_status2 >= datatual - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE AND final_status2 <= datatual) `

ou seja, não estou sabendo condicionar essa parte

Comment: Entendi, tenta com a segunda query

Comment: ufa funcionou,  acrescentei mais uma condição igual tu falou, e inverti a dataatual de lugar. Valeuuuu demais aí irmão, quebrou uma árvore e me ajudou pensar rsrs.  
  

`... WHERE  now() >= datahreg - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE AND now() <= datahreg`  

Tudibão e fica com Deus ;)

Comment: Prazer em te ajudar

Answer (score 1):

O `DATEDIFF` não funcionará para o seu caso porque, segundo a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff), o valor de resultado é expresso em dias, portanto não será possível verificar a diferença em minutos.

Uma alternativa é subtrair a data atual da coluna `datareg` usando a função [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) que possui um parâmetro para que você defina a unidade de tempo (no caso `MINUTE`) e assim o resultado será expresso em minutos:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabelax
 WHERE TIMEDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(), datareg) <= 2;
```

---

> [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)
>
> Returns `datetime_expr2 − datetime_expr1`, where `datetime_expr1` and `datetime_expr2` are date or datetime expressions.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna `datetime_expr2 − datetime_expr1`, onde `datetime_expr1` e `datetime_expr2` são expressões do tipo `date` ou `datetime`.

Comment: Olá Sorack obrigado pela atenção aí também irmão.  
  
cara até tentei usar o timestampdiff minute, mas o INTERVAL é o que está me deixando mais próximo do resultado que preciso.  
 
é que tenho a datahorareg: 2019-10-10 09:40:00  
e supondo que o now seria: 2019-10-10 09:38:00    
  
preciso que entre 09:38 e 09:40 que tem essa diferença de 02 minutos ele me retorne verdadeiro, caso seja 09:37 ou 09:41 ele não retornaria nada.     
  
tentei a sintaxe
`... AND (final_status2 >= datatual - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE AND final_status2 <= datatual)`  
 neste caso quase deu certo

Comment: O que acontece é que a sua data de registro é maior que a data atual (o que seria impossível porque neste caso o registro estaria vindo do futuro), porém neste cenário que você citou, basta inverter as datas no `TIMEDIFF`, colocando a data atual como primeiro parâmetro

Comment: sim sim verdade, mente tava bitolada e não prestei atenção nisso rsrs. Poxa de toda forma valeu demais pelas dicas.